# Thread safe, (almost) lock free, fast data structure used for heavy writes, then heavy reads

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm running some experiments, based on the .NET thread safe, and non-thread safe dictionary's, as well as my custom one.

The results for writing 20,000,000 (20 million) ints to each are as follows:

1. Non-thread safe: 909 milliseconds (less then 1 second) **Dictionary**
2. Thread safe: 11914 milliseconds  (more then 11 seconds) **ConcurrentDictionary**
3. Custom: 909 milliseconds (less then 1 second) **2 dictionary's**
4. Thread safe (ConcurrentTryAdd): 12697 milliseconds  (more then 12 seconds) **No better then #2**

These tests were conducted in a single threaded environment, I'm trying to get the speed of the non-thread safe dictionary, with the safety of the thread safe one.

The results are promising so far, I'm surprised how poorly the ConcurrentDictionary handled, maybe its meant for certain scenarios only?

Anyway, below is the code I used to test the three dictionary's, can you tell me if my custom one is thread safe? Do I have to add a lock to **if (_list.ContainsKey(threadId))**? I don't think so since its only a read, and when the dictionary has an element added to it (a write) its protected by a lock, blocking other threads trying to read it.

There is no locks once the thread has the dictionary, because another thread cannot write to that same dictionary, since each thread gets their own dictionary (based on the ManagedThreadId), making it as safe as a single thread.

> Main

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace LockFreeTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int i = 20000000;  // 20 million

            IWork work = new Custom(); // Replace with: Control(), Concurrent(), or Custom()
            work.Start(i);

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0}\r\nPress anykey to continue...", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

> Non-thread safe

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LockFreeTests
{
    class Control : IWork
    {
        public void Start(int i)
        {
            var list = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
            {
                list.Add(n, n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Thread safe

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace LockFreeTests
{
    class Concurrent : IWork
    {
        public void Start(int i)
        {
            var list = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
            for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
            {
                list.AddOrUpdate(n, n, (a, b) => b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Thread Safe (try add)

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace LockFreeTests
{
    class ConcurrentTryAdd : IWork
    {
        public void Start(int i)
        {
            var list = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
            for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
            {
                bool result = list.TryAdd(n, n);
                if (!result)
                {
                    n--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Custom

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace LockFreeTests
{
    class Custom : IWork
    {
        private static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> _list = null;

        static Custom()
        {
            _list = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>();
        }

        public void Start(int i)
        {
            int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            Dictionary<int, int> threadList = null;
            bool firstTime = false;

            lock (_list)
            {
                if (_list.ContainsKey(threadId))
                {
                     threadList = _list[threadId];
                }
                else
                {
                    threadList = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                    firstTime = true;
                 }
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
            {
                threadList.Add(n, n);
            }

            if (firstTime)
            {
                lock (_list)
                {
                    _list.Add(threadId, threadList);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> IWorK

```
namespace LockFreeTests
{
    public interface IWork
    {
        void Start(int i);
    }
}
```

### Multi-threaded Example

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LockFreeTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int totalWork = 20000000;  // 20 million
            int cores = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            int workPerCore = totalWork / cores;

            IWork work = new Custom(); // Replace with: Control(), Concurrent(), ConcurrentTryAdd(), or Custom()
            var tasks = new Task[cores];

            for (int n = 0; n < cores; n++)
            {
                tasks[n] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        work.Start(workPerCore);
                    });
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0}\r\nPress anykey to continue...", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code runs in 528 milliseconds, that's a 40% speed improvement (from the single thread test)

Comment: Will multiple threads work on the same list in the custom scenario? You check if this is the "first time", and then you put the dictionary into the list with the thread id. What happens when/if the thread id is reused? Also, you should lock around the check if the list is in the dictionary in the first place. The internal data structure of the dictionary is volatile while being updated, you should not try to read from it while that happens.

Comment: And why store it outside the method, why not just create a dictionary and store it in a local variable? What is this code supposed to measure/prove/disprove?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes the custom one is menat for multi-threaded environments.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I will test the try Add and update the question with the results. As for why its a dictionary it was just a random choice, nothing special. The end goal is to increase my working knowledge of threads, and in this case to get a fast thread safe generic list to read and write from.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The result of TryAdd was the same as AddOrUpdate.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can you please link to more efficient solutions? They need to be thread safe, and as fast as the non-thread safe versions. The data structure isn't important to me, as long as I can Add, Read, Update and Delete.

Comment: @HenkHolterman OK, concentrate example: I have 1000 web service calls to make every 5 minutes. I have methods to call these services, when I get a response, I save it in a queue. Later I go through this queue and save the responses to a database. I don't have the methods calling the webservices save the response, because I want to update the database in a deterministic way. This requirement comes about because the database gets many thousands of requests every second by many different applications.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Your an ass. You ask me for a specific and realistic context, then I give you one, then you tell me that isn't appropriate and to make it a new question. I realize you're giving your free time to answer me here, but still I find our conversation chain, somewhat unbelievable.

Comment: The most efficient lock-free dictionary I'm aware of is Cliff's [non-blocking hashmap](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2007-03-26-non-blocking-hashtable). The code is open source and for Java, but Java and C# are exceedingly similar and you can learn a lot from the design in any case. Actually I see several possible improvements a C# version could make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not thread-safe.

> Do I have to add a lock to if (_list.ContainsKey(threadId))?  I don't think so since its only a read, and when the dictionary has an element added to it (a write) its protected by a lock, blocking other threads trying to read it.

Yes, you do need a lock here to make it thread-safe.

Comment: Also, he has the standard misconception about what a `lock` does, it does not prevent other threads for using the object being locked, except if they too lock on the same object. Since reading does not lock, it will read just fine while the lock is in place.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks I did have that misconception, know I now better.

Comment: Note that managed thread ids will be reused. Once a thread finishes, its id can be reused. It's not just theoretical either, out of 1000 threads I created here, I got only 442 unique ids.

Comment: I'd say it is now thread-safe, though it doesn't do anything useful in its current form, and isn't equivalent to the alternate versions.

Comment: @joe what alternate versions? Because it seems much better (in speed) than ConcurrentDictionary. Could you link to examples of these other versions please?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen As long as no two threads exist at the same time with the same id I think its ok right? The point isn't to have a dictionary per thread, the point is to have only one thread at a time have access to one dictionary.

Comment: Your alternate "thread-safe" and "non-thread-safe" versions both create a Dictionary<int,int>, which you don't create with your custom version.  So your code may be faster but it's not doing the same thing.  And since you never use the dictionary you create, what you're measuring doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @Joe My custom code still does the same Dictionary<int,int>, as a matter of fact it does that and more then the other code does. The custom code has a dictionary around the Dictionary<int,int>. So accessing the Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> isn't thread safe, but accessing the Dictionary<int,int> (value) is. See the for loop? its the same loop as all the other code, so I think it's a fair comparison.

Comment: @Joe Woops, the **_list** field in the custom was an instance variable, I changed it static. The point is that many threads can call start, updating a central list in a fast, thread safe manner.

Comment: @user1515024 - "My custom code still does the same Dictionary<int,int>, " - no, it does a *different* dictionary; one that is specific to each thread so doesn't have the same synchronization needs.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote about my lock-free thread-safe copy-on-write dictionary implementation here:

http://www.singulink.com/CodeIndex/post/fastest-thread-safe-lock-free-dictionary

It is very fast for quick bursts of writes and lookups usually run at 100% standard `Dictionary` speed without locking. If you write occasionally and read often, this is the fastest option available.